# how to display list of orders from my database in vue js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

i've successfully updated my orders after payment please how can i display it in my vue front end

this is my html template which shows the list of orders made

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      v-for="order in orders"
      :key="order._id"
    >
      <div
        v-for="product in order.products"
        :key="product._id"
      >

        <a href="#">{{ product.productID.title }}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

this is my script tag

```
<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "Products",
  data() {
    return {
      orders: [],
      name: "",
      email: ""
    };
  },
  created() {
    //user is not authorized
    if (localStorage.getItem("token") === null) {
      this.$router.push("/login");
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/api/orders", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer" + token,
          "x-access-token": token
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);

        orders: res.products;
      });

    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/user", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer" + token,
          "x-access-token": token
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.name = res.data.user.name;
        this.email = res.data.user.email;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

this the json object i get in my console

```
[
    {
        "_id": "62d163b638cbafee24c6d663",
        "products": [
            {
                "productID": {
                    "_id": "625672a8370e769a8a93a51e",
                    "reviews": [],
                    "owner": {
                        "_id": "6220db7ee861f3dbbaf21e3d",
                        "name": "mr jacob",
                        "about": "hello",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    "category": "62566ec30e42d6c5ab370e7c",
                    "title": "galaxy note",
                    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ",
                    "photo": "https://aji.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/1649832580792",
                    "price": 300,
                    "stockQuantity": 1,
                    "__v": 0,
                    "id": "625672a8370e769a8a93a51e"
                },
                "quantity": 1,
                "price": 300,
                "_id": "62d163b638cbafee24c6d664"
            }
        ],
        "owner": {
            "_id": "6278e8bc1966b7d3783ced8e",
            "name": "bas",
            "email": "bas@gmail.com",
            "password": "$2a$10$3QkbA805Pn/QBYMd6sULi.FGjETYoMf44wuV1mtOZahhPzm5zeL4G",
            "__v": 0,
            "address": "62b2cfd8d0846785cd87c64d"
        },
        "estimatedDelivery": "",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

i'm not getting any error in my console so i don't seem to know where the problem is

Comment: `orders: res.products` does nothing.  What do you think it actually does. btw, it's valid syntax so wont throw an error, but it does nothing at all. Did you mean `this.orders = res.products`

Comment: It should be `this.orders = res` instead of `this.orders = res.products`

Comment: @jibzy It should be `product.productID.title` instead of `product.productID.tile`

Comment: @RohìtJíndal check the the error i posted it "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')"

Comment: @RohìtJíndal no error and i'm not getting a response in my template , i would appreciate if i can get a live example on stack editor

Comment: @jibzy I added an answer. Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.orders = res.data.products was what solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine to me and it is working fine. One small observation, As per the console data you posted, It should be `this.orders = res` instead of `orders = res.products`.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    orders: []
  },
  mounted() {
    const apiResponse = [
      {
        "_id": "62d163b638cbafee24c6d663",
        "products": [
          {
            "productID": {
              "_id": "625672a8370e769a8a93a51e",
              "reviews": [],
              "owner": {
                "_id": "6220db7ee861f3dbbaf21e3d",
                "name": "mr jacob",
                "about": "hello",
                "__v": 0
              },
              "category": "62566ec30e42d6c5ab370e7c",
              "title": "galaxy note",
              "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ",
              "photo": "https://aji.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/1649832580792",
              "price": 300,
              "stockQuantity": 1,
              "__v": 0,
              "id": "625672a8370e769a8a93a51e"
            },
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": 300,
            "_id": "62d163b638cbafee24c6d664"
          }
        ],
        "owner": {
          "_id": "6278e8bc1966b7d3783ced8e",
          "name": "bas",
          "email": "bas@gmail.com",
          "password": "$2a$10$3QkbA805Pn/QBYMd6sULi.FGjETYoMf44wuV1mtOZahhPzm5zeL4G",
          "__v": 0,
          "address": "62b2cfd8d0846785cd87c64d"
        },
        "estimatedDelivery": "",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ];
    this.orders = apiResponse;
  }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div
       v-for="order in orders"
       :key="order._id"
       >
    <div
         v-for="product in order.products"
         :key="product._id"
         >
      <a href="#">{{ product.productID.title }}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this.orders = res.data.products;  was what solved my issues thanks for your time